# no main manifest attribute, in path/backend-app.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I am writing a simple spring web application. Following is my main SpringBootApplication class:

```
package com.example.backendapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendAppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I would like to create jar and then later use it in Dockerfile.

To create a jar I followed the steps on IntelliJ: Build > Build Artifacts > backend-app.jar > Build

This creates the jar as well under the out folder:
[image]

I am trying to run the jar from terminal using the command:

```
java -jar out/artifacts/backend_app_jar/backend-app.jar
```

But it keeps on giving me following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in out/artifacts/backend_app_jar/backend-app.jar
```

I checked following files:

1. build/resources/main/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and it has following details:

   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Main-Class: com.example.backendapp.BackendAppApplication
2. out/production/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and it has following details:

   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Main-Class: com.example.backendapp.BackendAppApplication

In build.gradle I have:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.backendapp.BackendAppApplication"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What is the correct way to create a jar in IntelliJ? Our my MANIFEST.MF files missing something that is required?

Comment: Have a look at the jar file. Does it have the manifest in it? Make sure you're building via gradle.

Comment: Please provide the content of your gradle.build file. You are missing spring-boot-gradle-plugin.

Comment: @tgdavies I tried the command "jar tf backend-app.jar > log.txt" and I do see manifest file in it:
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/example/
com/example/backendapp/
com/example/backendapp/BackendAppApplication.class
com/example/backendapp/controller/
com/example/backendapp/controller/FileController.class
com/example/backendapp/model/
com/example/backendapp/model/FileUploadRequest.class
META-INF/
org/
...

Comment: @tgdavies yes, before creating this I ran the command: gradle clean build

Comment: @DhavalGajjar in the plugins section?
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

Comment: @DhavalGajjar Added my build.gradle in question as well. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: How did you create the jar? I suspect the export from Intellij instead of using your Gradle build.

Comment: @M. Deinum I ran the command "gradle build clean" as well tried through Build > Build Artifacts > Build option

Comment: I did not find a solution on how to solve this, but I created another project and downgraded my Java version to Java 11. On gradle build, the jar is getting created properly as well as I am able to run the jar file successfully.

Comment: ehrm `gradle build clean`? You first build and then ditch everything? I would also expect the jar to be in `build/libs` not in the out directory. The out directory is from intellij, the `build/libs` is from gradle.

Comment: jar was present in build/libs folder as well @M.Deinum. I tried running jars from both folder locations. Both gave me same errors.

Comment: You shouldn't need the modification of the jar type in your gradle file, Spring Boot plugin will generate the manifest automatically. So I would remove the part of modifying the manifest (I never needed the task etc. if you really want the spring boot plugin allows setting the main class through a property no need to modify that yourself through the manifest task).